# selenium2.0 webelement cannot get Attribute of the html

Tags: xpath, selenium, getattribute

I used pagefactory mode, and in my bean file, i declare the WebElement by using xpath:

```
@FindBy(xpath ='//div[5]/div/div/dl/dd[4]')
def public WebElement nextPage //nextpage
```

and in my factory file(this class extends the bean class), i used

```
nextPage.getAttribute("class")
```

but the result return me a null or empty. i dont know why...I just want to get the class of the following html, to judge if this is a clickable link or a common text.

here is the html:

```
<a class="easyquery_paginglink" href='javascript:gotoPage("consumeRecord","consumeRecord",2)'>nextpage</a>
```

Comment: This is what I think you are asking: _I am using Selenium WebDriver to select an element on the page with an XPath and wish to get its class attribute._
Is this correct? If so can you post the error message you get, the html source of the element you are trying to get and your current xpath code.

Comment: yes,that's the question. no error message display, only null or empty result returns when i using getAttribute("class")...

Comment: this is the html<a class="easyquery_paginglink" href='javascript:gotoPage("consumeRecord","consumeRecord",3)'>nextpage</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath could be "//a[Text() = 'nextpage']" then use .getAttribute("class");
So:

```
IWebElement element = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[Text() = 'nextpage']"));
string className = element.GetAttribute("class");
```